# Late 2009 Macbook - Has Anyone Tried 16GB of Ram?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

Just curious if anyone has tried maxing out the ram on a late 2009 Macbook (white, not pro) to 16GB running El Capitan or Yosemite?

[Everymac's page](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.26-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-late-2009-specs.html) states that the max is 8GB. Why not 16GB?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The chipset and processor may not support more RAM, even though you can physically put it in. You can always try. Weird behaviour and instability result from that.

Comment: Correct. While they can add more RAM physically, it won't recognize it if that amount is not supported (let alone the type).